# Blurry Semantic UI icon

Tags: css, font-awesome, semantic-ui

When increasing font size, Semantic UI icons are getting blurred. I do understand why but since Semantic UI icons depends on Font Awesome which has different sizes, I'm wondering if there is already a built-in support with Sementact UI do achieve the same?

[image: normal size]
[image: blurred (with 1.14em)]

```
<i class="plus icon"></i>
```

Comment: Does it looks blurry on every browser?

Comment: For me, in IE and FF it looks blurry as well but not as bad as Chrome. Screnshots are made using Chrome. (I'm increasing font size using `font-size: 1.14em`.)

Comment: Can confirm that some UI components are blurry in Chrome on both Windows and Linux. https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2007